# EF Code First: Trying to get a child property's parameters to appear in the parent class' table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a class, "Search". See definition below:

```
public class Search
{
    [Key]
    public int SearchID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    public SearchParameters SearchParameters { get; set; }

    public ICollection<SearchProvider> SearchProviders { get; set; }
    public User User;
}
```

SearchParameters is a class with value types, and a few sub-classes; as defined below:

```
public class SearchParameters
{
    public List<string> SearchTerms { get; set; }
    public int MaxRecords { get; set; }
    public DistanceParameter Distance { get; set; }
    public PriceRangeParameter PriceRange { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is that I do not want a separate SearchParameters table that has to link to the Search table because every property of the search is always one to one (Except for SearchTerms). Really, what I want EF to do is 'bring up' the child classes' properties so we end up with All the properties of SearchParameter in the SearchTable (and all the parameters of the DistanceParameter and PriceRangeParameter objects themselves). What annotations or other logic would I need for this to work? Thanks!

Comment: I may be wrong so I am not putting this as an answer but at least something to look at. I am pretty sure this is a limitation of the EF code-first interface. I believe that based on how EF works it makes a table for each class that is defined and links using keys. That being said what you would need to do is either create the table yourself and manually do it with SQL or write the class into one class, a suggestion would be to inherit interfaces which could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think EF Complex Type mapping is what you need, see more here:

http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2011/03/28/associations-in-ef-4-1-code-first-part-2-complex-types.aspx

Comment: This is close! Now to see if I can get the subtype of the subtype to work. Will mark as answer if I can figure that out, and will post my findings as a comment

Comment: So I am getting an error trying to do complex types. I manually added the 'ComplexType' decoration to DistanceParameter and PriceRangeParameter, and moved all the fields up so its simply one type with two complex types instead of a complex type inside of other complex types. 

 error 3004: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 43:No mapping specified for properties Search.DistanceParameter, Search.PriceRangeParameter in Set Searches.
An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
 Entity is type [Core.Search.Data.Search]

Comment: Issue solved; had a child class with a FK and complex types and FKs don't work well together.